# How can tikzpictures in a tabular be centered independent of nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I have the following `tikzpicture` inside a `tabular` and i would like to have the circles to be centered such that they line up in collumns and rows, even if there are nodes at different positions. How can this be done?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \draw (0, 0) circle (1cm);
        \draw (90:1.3) node {$A$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \draw (0, 0) circle (1cm);
        \draw (-90:1.3) node {$B$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \\
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \draw (0, 0) circle (1cm);
        \draw (0:1.3) node {$C$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \draw (0, 0) circle (1cm);
        \draw (180:1.3) node {$D$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The nodes make the center of a `tikzpicture` move away from the center of the circles. Can the center be set manually to the center of the circles? Or is there any option that makes `tikzpicture` ignore the nodes?

Comment: You could add `overlay` at the node path. How automatic should this be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the option `overlay` to the second path (by the way, why don’t you use `\node at (90:1.3) {$A$}:`?) the path (and the node) is ignored in the computation of the bounding box, but this would make them protrude in the neighbor cells of the `tabular`.

The following solution resets the bounding box at the end of the picture and replaces it with its own which is a rectangle (a square actually) around one point, the syntax is

```
center around={<distance>:(<point>)}
```

The `<distance>` needs to be given manually as the nodes have different heights and widths. Otherwise one needs to calculate the biggest TikZ picture of all four which would require a second pass and the need of the `.aux` file.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{%
  center around/.style args={#1:(#2)}{%
    execute at end picture={%
      \pgfresetboundingbox
      \path[use as bounding box, reset cm] (#2) circle [radius={#1}];
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
{\tikzset{every picture/.append style={center around={1.5cm:(0,0)}}}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \draw (0, 0) circle (1cm);
        \draw (90:1.3) node {$A$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \draw (0, 0) circle (1cm);
        \draw (-90:1.3) node {$B$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \\
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \draw (0, 0) circle (1cm);
        \draw (0:1.3) node {$C$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \draw (0, 0) circle (1cm);
        \draw (180:1.3) node {$D$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

### Output (the bounding box path is drawn with `help lines`)

[image]